# Change Item value inside a ListBox

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have the following ListBox, in a Windows Store App project

```
<ListBox x:Name="ContractIndicators"  Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Indicators, ElementName=pageRoot}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedIndicator, ElementName=pageRoot, Mode=TwoWay}"
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemStyle}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"   />
```

That uses this style

```
<Style x:Key="ItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates" >
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0" To="{StaticResource AccentColor}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0"  To="{StaticResource AccentColor}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0"  To="{StaticResource AccentColor}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0"  To="{StaticResource AccentColor}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" IsHitTestVisible="False" Fill="Transparent" Margin="5"
                               Width="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                               Height="{Binding Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The ListBox has a biding to

```
private ObservableCollection<object> indicators = new ObservableCollection<object>();
```

and this is the type of items the collection contains

```
public class Indicator
{
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public Indicator(string image)
    {
        Image = image;
    }
}
```

what i want is to change the Image field inside the selected item in the ListBox
how can i get this done?

[image: ListBox]
This is what my ListBox Shows, what i want is to have that Green icon, depending on what item is selected
if i clicked item 4 , that item would pass to Green color
wich would mean that the Image field in my Indicator Object that is inside the ListBox at that Index would be updated

Comment: Can you please elaborate more as to what you are trying to accomplish, or provide an example.

Comment: added a image, maybe it helps to see better what i want. Basically i want to change the images from gray to green depending on what item is selected in the ListBox

Comment: One approach would be add a OnValueChanged event to your ListBox so that when a new item is selected you can modify the VisualState appropriately. Also, you should modify the To="SomeColor", this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.coloranimation(v=vs.110).aspx) to the documentation on ColorAnimation might help.

Comment: There are a couple of ways you can do it. Firstly, you can add an `IsSelected` property to your `Indicator` class. Secondly, you could add a `SelectedIndicator` property to your ViewModel and then use a Converter which checks the ViewModel's `SelectedIndicator` property.

Comment: i will try these ideas tomorrow :)